# Set TYPO3 page cache lifetime to an exact month (and not 31 days)

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

i have a page with a TYPO3 plugin, that shows the "tip of the month". I populated items in the list module, having a start/end date to the respective month.

The thing is I have to either disable the cache (or set it to only 1 day) or flush it manually, or the tip of the last month is still shown.
I want the page to be cached, but the cache only be valid until the 1st of each month. Setting page lifetime in the background to "1 month", actually sets a lifetime of 2678400 seconds (31 days), which would not work on months shorter than 31 days. Or is there already a functionality behind it, calculating the actual length of the current month!? (I can't wait a full month to test it.)

I know there is `cache.lifetime` available in TypoScript, but you can only set an **integer** (amount in seconds), "**unlimited**" (no expiration until flushed), "**default**" (as configured in config.cache_period) or **stdWrap**.

I know that the last created cache datetime is sent via "Date" header in the response. So TYPO3 should somewhere know this timestamp.

So I would need something like:

```
<?php
    $dateStart = new DateTime( $pageLastCreated_whencever );
    $dateEnd = new DateTime();
    $dateEnd->modify( 'first day of +1 month' );
    $dateDiff = $dateStart->diff($dateEnd);
    return $dateDiff->format('%s'); // equals cache lifetime
?>
```

Could someone push me in the right direction?
I would love to avoid having to use a user function, though...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "I want the page to be cached, but the cache only be valid until the 1st of each month"? Do you want all cache to be invalidated on the 1. of every month at once? If yes, I would not do this by lifetime but set lifetime to longer and flush the cache. What do you want to achieve with your mechism?

Comment: @SybillePeters Since I asked that question more than 6 years ago and am no longer a typo3 developer for about 5 years, I cannot tell you the exact purpose or circumstances from then. I vaguely remember that there was content to be displayed, that has to be invalidated at exactly the 1st of each month and therefore requiring the page cache to be invalidated. Since the length of each calendar month is not the same, a fixed number for `cache.lifetime` could not be applied.
I stumbled upon a potential solution as stated in another comment, but I cannot remember the result anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't harm to clear the cache in TYPO3 from time to time.

I would recommend to use [`config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 1`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#cache-clearatmidnight) so you are sure that your update shows on the first of each month. Then you could use a schedular task to rebuild the cache right after clearing.

**Edit**

I looked a bit through the docs, and what you can definitely do is to wrap the `cache_clearAtMidnight` in a typoscript condition that checks if [the dayofmonth](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Index.html) is smaller than two.

This would be your full typoscript that goes to your page setup. No php needed.

```
[dayofmonth < 2]
  config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 1
[global]
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but how do I actually achieve the automatism of cache lifetime till the first of the following month? I don't know if my sample code would actually work (and how to do it in TypoScript), or where I could get the date of the last page creation.

Comment: I updated the answer. Don't worry to much about the lifetime. Your page is cached until you clear it.

Comment: Let's walk through an example:   It's 2016-07-31 23:59 and it turns to 2016-08-01 00:00. Only then the condition is valid and the configuration you suggested is set. But midnight is over. Doesn't it mean that the cache is cleared on 2016-08-02 00:00 instead?

Comment: I know I can flush the cache manually every time I want, but I want to have the page cached a specific (but not constant) amount of time and the cache flushed automatically (for this page) then.

Comment: I just red the following at the docs regarding `config.cache_clearAtMidnight`: "*With this setting the cache always expires at midnight of the day, the page is scheduled to expire.*" (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#cache-clearatmidnight) --- Doesn't that mean I still have to calculate and set `cache_period` or `cache_timeout`?

Comment: I could answer myself the situation in my example: It's not exactly midnight, but the next page-call after midnight of the day the cache is set to "run out". --- On the other hand I may have found a solution: (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#cache)
`config.cache.<page-id> = <table-name>:<pid>` (*page-id* ... the page you define the cache for; *table-name* ... the table of the stored elements to consider their start/end times; *pid* ... the page on which those elements are stored) --- I'll test that as well...

Comment: How do you do the cache warmup by scheduler task? There is no scheduler task, which does this by default, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out the cache time is done in seconds. The only solution would be to use a custom scheduler task which clears the cache by your needs

Comment: And how do I setup individual cache-lifetimes per page, and how do I recognize and interpret them by the scheduler?

Comment: That logic would be 100% up to you. Create a simple table with colums "page id" and "lifetime" and check every call if the requirement is met. If done, you can call the cachemanager and clear it for those pages.

Comment: So I would additionally have to set up a kind of BackEnd module (admin tool) to actually populate and maintain the cache lifetime of each page. Or I would have to write an extension extending the page configuration to be able to set it conveniently... --- As I stated I wouldn't even want to use a user function. And now I would have to write a whole extension. Well I guess I have to at least consider it if everything else fails...

Comment: it would be a simple `CommandController`which would be used as scheduler task. You can already set cache tags in the page properties which would then be cleared.