# How to do cache warmup in TYPO3

Tags: caching, typo3, typo3-9.x

[In another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146675/set-typo3-page-cache-lifetime-to-an-exact-month-and-not-31-days), there is the recommendation to setup a `cache_clearAtMidnight` via TypoScript and do a subsequent cache warmup.

I would like to know how to do this cache warmup because I did not find a scheduler task to do it.

(Clearing the entire cache once a day seems excessive, but the cache warmup seems like a good idea to me in any case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't know whether there is an internal mechanism in TYPO3 for cache warming, I built my own little cache warmer based around a simple PHP script (can actually be anything – Python, PHP, Bash,...). The script **reads the sitemap.xml and requests each page via cURL**.

I use a custom user agent to exclude these requests from statistics.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'cache warming - TYPO3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ext. Its simple wget wrapper but you can add it as Scheduler task.

https://github.com/visuellverstehen/t3fetch

Comment: I think it is good to see various solutions. But t3fetch does nothing to filter out URLs. The recursive wget crawls incrementally following the links and will also fetch files in fileadmin, typo3, typo3conf etc. For warming up the page caches this is not necessary and will increase the time this takes to run (e.g. on large sites). Additionally, I see no advantage on running a command line script from a TYPO3 extension which uses no TYPO3 functionality.

Comment: Sybille - nice catch about fetching the not needed resource! This should be of course improved. 
Nevermind can you tell me if b13/warmup will warmup single view of records - or only pages? For crawler you need to configure it to crawl by single view of records and sometimes when url of single records is complex its quite hard to configure crawler ext.

Comment: I am currently using wget, actually. I am aware of these other solutions, but have not really used them for cache warmup. I can't answer your question right now. I will be looking at some of these solutions more in depth now. In case I find out something interesting, I will update my answer.

Comment: For wget I also use -t1 (to retry only once) and exclude some directories, e.g. -X "fileadmin,typo3,typo3conf,typo3temp,uploads" and --spider etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated (Feb 14, 2024):**

There is an extension [warming](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/warming) by Elias Häußler which warms up the page cache by using the sitempa.

You can also do an initial warmup of some caches (not a full warmup of all pages) by using TYPO3 core functionality:

```
php vendor/bin/typo3 cache:warmup -h
```

e.g.

```
php vendor/bin/typo3 cache:warmup
```

---

Btw, `cache_clearAtMidnight` does not *clear* the cache at midnight, it sets the expire time to be at midnight. Once the cache has been expired, on next page hit, it will be regenerated. Has the same effect, but might be good to know.

Comment: Sybille - can you tell me if b13/warmup will warmup single view of records - or only pages? For crawler you need to configure it additionally to crawl by single view of records and sometimes when url of single records is complex its quite hard to configure crawler ext.